# Perplexing mathmatical problem due to grammar

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I recently read a post on Facebook regarding a mathmatical problem posed by a statement without commas.  I was hoping that this site could provide a correct grammatical translation of the following statement:  1 rabbit saw 6 elephants while going to the river. Every elephant saw 2 monkeys going towards the river. Every monkey holds 1 parrot in their hands.  How many animals are going towards the river?

Comment: Ah, the old [St Ives rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_I_was_going_to_St_Ives).  "As I was going to St Ives, I **met** a man with seven wives ...  How many were going **to** St Ives?"

Comment: would the statement "1 rabbit saw, 6 elephants while going to the river". mean the same as "1 rabbit saw 6 elephants, while going to the river"?

Comment: This question belongs on https://puzzles.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't agree.  It is a grammar question.

Comment: There's nothing ambiguous about the (non-)use of commas.  What's ambiguous is the direction of some of the animals.

Comment: "1 rabbit saw, 6 elephants while going to the river" is nonsense.

Comment: As GV notes, it is a question of grammar. In the second sentence does the participle phrase modify elephant or monkeys?

Comment: The riddle [is already on Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63470/a-simple-one).  ***This*** question is ***about*** the riddle, and, since the riddle is written in English, *this* question is as on-topic here as, say, any [tag:grammatical-number] question.  I’m voting to leave closed for lack of research (and not even including a link to the Facebook post).

Comment: @Scott - It's not on topic because it's (intentionally) making use of *ambiguity* in the language.  All we can say here is that it's ambiguous.  If the OP cannot understand *why* the wording is ambiguous then that would be a (different) question.

Comment: So, if the OP doesn’t understand *that* it’s ambiguous, and asks simply what it means, he’s shown the door.  They have to realize that it’s ambiguous and ask why in order to get an answer?  The comment “What’s ambiguous is the direction of some of the animals.” isn’t even particularly on point; the “St. Ives” comparison aside, more people seem to be tripped up by the ***number*** of monkeys.  It’s easy to sympathize with the people who feel that Stack Exchange is unfriendly to newcomers.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are **5** animals going to the river (for certain). The 6 elephants may or may not have been going towards the river. The elephants may all have seen the same 2 monkeys. Had **each** elephant seen 2 monkeys, there would have been at least 25 animals going to the river. And if the elephants were also heading to the river while each one saw 2 monkeys, there would have been a total of 31 animals. But without any further information, you can only say with certainty that there were 5 animals going to the river.

> 1 rabbit saw 6 elephants while going to the river.

1 (the rabbit)

> Every elephant saw 2 monkeys going towards the river.

2 (monkeys, seen by every elephant)

> Every monkey holds 1 parrot in their hands.

2 (parrots)

> How many animals are going towards the river?

1 + 2 + 2 = 5

Answer (score -1):

You Are Correct There are 11 Animals 1 Rabbit Saw 6 Elephants (7) Elephants Saw 2 Monkeys With Each Had A Parrot On Them (4) So 7+4=11 So Yes

Comment: If each elephant saw two monkeys going towards the river then the elephants must have been going the other way, no?

Comment: @HotLicks We can't know for sure, maybe the monkeys ran in front of the elephants.

Comment: @JJJ - You can tell for sure by examining the stuff between the elephants' toes.

Comment: @HotLicks I trust the elephant(s), you really should be wary of the rabbits though. Rabbits probably can't even count (unlike the other animals that have been shown to have that ability) so they really are incompetent witnesses.